# Matplotlib Half color axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am using matplotlib to make some plots and I have run into a few difficulties that I need help with.

problem 1) In order to keep a consistent colorscheme I need to only use half of the color axis. There are only positive values, so I want the zero values to be green, the mid values to be yellow and the highest values to be red. The color scheme that most closely matches this is  gist_rainbow_r, but I only want the top half of it.

problem 2) I can't seem to figure out how to get the colorbar on the right hand side of the plot to show up or how to get it to let me label the axes.

If it helps, I am using the latest version of Anaconda wth the latext version of matplotlib

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow_r')
edosfig2 = plt.figure(2)
edossub2 = edosfig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
edossub2 = plt.contourf(eVec,kints,smallEDOS,cmap=cmap)
edosfig2.show()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a specific set of colors that you want to use for you colormap, you can build it based on those.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('name', ['green', 'yellow', 'red'])

# Generate some data similar to yours
y, x = np.mgrid[-200:1900, -300:2000]
z = np.cos(np.hypot(x, y) / 100) + 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cax = ax.contourf(x, y, z, cmap=cmap)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
cbar.set_label('Z-Values')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

However, if you did just want the top half of some particularly complex colormap, you can copy a portion of it by evaluating the colormap over the range you're interested in.  For example, if you wanted the "top" half, you'd evaluate it from 0.5 to 1:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# Evaluate an existing colormap from 0.5 (midpoint) to 1 (upper end)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('gist_earth')
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0.5, 1, cmap.N // 2))

# Create a new colormap from those colors
cmap2 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Upper Half', colors)

y, x = np.mgrid[-200:1900, -300:2000]
z = np.cos(np.hypot(x, y) / 100) + 1

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
for ax, cmap in zip(axes.flat, [cmap, cmap2]):
    cax = ax.imshow(z, cmap=cmap, origin='lower',
                    extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
    cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
    cbar.set_label(cmap.name)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question though. How do you make the transitions be more continuous like the built in colormaps. These are good, but the transitions are very abrupt.

Comment: @RobertHembree - Unless I'm misunderstanding something, they appear abrupt because you're using `contourf` (which has a set number of levels) instead of something like `imshow` (which is continuous).  Or am I misunderstanding what you're asking?

Comment: Using imshow as you suggested seems to have solved my problem. I tried to get all of this out of the documentation. Thank you very much. It all works perfectly now.

Comment: +1 for second half of your post. Exactly what I was looking for, when taking only upper half of the bwr-colormap (i.e. the white to red transition) for plots with only positive numbers, and same colorcoding for plots with both positive and negative numbers.